# Wrong line-drawing characters when write "tree" command output to file

Tags: macos, command-line, textedit, encoding

Under macOS Catalina 10.15.1, Using the standard "tree" command (as supplied by MacPorts), if at the Terminal prompt I `cd` to a folder and then execute `tree` there,  I get output like this:

```
.
├── Activity\ Monitor.app
├── ApplicationsFolderIcon.icns
├── BBEdit.app
├── Backup
│   ├── Backup\ and\ Sync\ from\ Google.app
│   ├── Carbon\ Copy\ Cloner.app
│   ├── Dropbox.app\ 
│   ├── ForeverSave\ 2.app
│   ├── Get\ Backup\ Pro\ 3.app
```

However, if I redirect the output to a text file, as in

```
tree > myapps.txt
```

then I get wrong characters when I view the file in TextEdit:

```
.
‚îú‚îÄ‚îÄ Activity\ Monitor.app
‚îú‚îÄ‚îÄ ApplicationsFolderIcon.icns
‚îú‚îÄ‚îÄ BBEdit.app
‚îú‚îÄ‚îÄ Backup
‚îÇ¬†¬† ‚îú‚îÄ‚îÄ Backup\ and\ Sync\ from\ Google.app
‚îÇ¬†¬† ‚îú‚îÄ‚îÄ Carbon\ Copy\ Cloner.app
‚îÇ¬†¬† ‚îú‚îÄ‚îÄ Dropbox.app\ 
‚îÇ¬†¬† ‚îú‚îÄ‚îÄ ForeverSave\ 2.app
‚îÇ¬†¬† ‚îú‚îÄ‚îÄ Get\ Backup\ Pro\ 3.app
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Try > myfile.rtf

Comment: I tried that (writing to ~/Desktop), and the file gets written...BUT even though I see the file on the desktop, when I try to open it, either by double-clicking it I get a pop-up error 'The document "myfile.rtf'' could not be opened'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either of these to get compatible characters.

```
tree --charset=ascii > a.txt
tree --charset unicode > a.txt
```

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127063/tree-command-output-with-pure-7-bit-ascii-output

Comment: With default Preferences for TextEdit.app, the version with `tree --charset=ascii` and redirecting to a file is working perfectly. Thank you!